# Why does Java not do type inference?

Tags: java, programming-languages, type-systems, data-types

I have always wondered why Java does not do type inference given that the language is what it is, and its VM is very mature. Google's Go is an example of a language with excellent type inference and it reduces the amount of typing one has to do. Is there any special reason behind this feature not being a part of Java?

Comment: backwards compatibility rules in a language as old and popular as java

Comment: @ratchetfreak Could type inference not be added in a backwards-compatible way? Older programs would just be providing more type information than necessary.

Comment: It may have some unintended effects when used with Type Erasure. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html

Comment: Write a whole hell of a lot more code once. Create new problems by solving simple problems with extreme prejudice everywhere.

Comment: Note that Java 8 will bring *a lot* of type inference with its Lambda feature: you can write complex lambdas without mentioning any types and everything being inferred.

Comment: @Brian Marshall: Sure, it could be added. Also, no language is perfect and there are many other nice features out there that could be added to Java (or to any other language, for that matter), but if you keep adding new features to a language it becomes bloated and looses coherence. After a certain point, extension is better done through libraries and tools than through new language features.

Comment: That's e.g. one reason why Java was not made backward compatible with C++: New features were introduced, existing features were dropped, a new design and a new name were chosen.

Comment: @Giorgio "why Java was not made backward compatible with C++" I think it isn't backwards compatible because it is a completely different language, with a syntactical similarity.

Comment: @Glenn Nelson: What I meant is that Java has so many features that make it different from C++ that it would have been difficult to develop it as an extension of C++. If it is difficult to fit certain new features into an existing language it can be better to start a new one. More recent examples are Scala or other JVM languages that were not designed as Java extensions.

Comment: If by type inference you mean something similar to Hindley-Milner algorithm, it is not very compatible with subtyping and overloading. And you would not really want a type system as complicated as in, say, Nemerle, in such a basic and trivial language as Java.

Comment: @SK-logic: I agree with you that type inference should not be added to Java. Only, "trivial" sounds like a negative way of describing Java: I think Java was designed as a simple language on purpose. This is a useful feature e.g. in complex projects involving large teams (KISS principle). So I think Java's simplicity is a feature not a bug. For these reasons, I do not like that Oracle wants to make it larger and larger (to maintain its "coolness"). IMHO Java was born as a simple language with a rich library and it should stay like this.

Comment: @Giorgio, of course it's great that Java is trivial. Just "simple" is not enough. And it's Java being trivial makes it so easy to implement powerful IDEs and code analysis tools for it.

Comment: How exactly does Go have excellent type inference? It only has really basic local type inference.

Comment: Local variable type inference is coming to Java: [JEP 286: Local-Variable Type Inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Technically speaking, Java does have *type inferencing* when using generics. With a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) like

```
public <T> T foo(T t) {
  return t;
}
```

The compiler will analyze and understand that when you write

```
// String
foo("bar");
// Integer
foo(new Integer(42));
```

A String is going to be returned for the first call and an Integer for the second call based on what was input as an argument. You will get the proper compile-time checking as a result. Additionally, in Java 7, one can get some additional type inferencing when [instantiating generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) like so

```
Map<String, String> foo = new HashMap<>();
```

Java is kind enough to fill in the blank angle brackets for us. Now why doesn't Java support *type inferencing* as a part of variable assignment? At one point, there was an [RFE](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4459053) for type inferencing in variable declarations, but this was closed as "Will not fix" because

> Humans benefit from the redundancy of the type declaration in two ways.
> First, the redundant type serves as valuable documentation - readers do
> not have to search for the declaration of getMap() to find out what type
> it returns.
> Second, the redundancy allows the programmer to declare the intended type,
> and thereby benefit from a cross check performed by the compiler.

The contributor who closed this also noted that it just feels "un-java-like", which I am one to agree with. Java's verbosity can be both a blessing and a curse, but it does make the language what it is.

Of course that particular RFE was not the end of that conversation. During Java 7, this feature was [again considered](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/forax/2006/12/17/call-me-santa), with some test implementations being created, including one by James Gosling himself. Again, this feature was ultimately shot down.

With the release of Java 8, we now get type inference as a part of lambdas as such:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Tom", "Dick", "Harry");
Collections.sort(names, (first, second) -> first.compareTo(second));
```

The Java compiler is able to look at the method [`Collections#sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) and then the interface of [`Comparator#compare(T o1, T o2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-) and determine that `first` and `second` should be a `String` thus allowing the programmer to forgo having to restate the type in the lambda expression.

Comment: `First, the redundant type serves as valuable documentation - readers do not have to search for the declaration of getMap() to find out what type it returns` - yes, if it's `HashMap<String, Integer> map = foo.getMap()` then I agree - in C# I typically don't use `var` in such cases, even though I could. But this argument does not hold water if it's `HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>()`. This is true redundancy and I see no benefit in having to write the type name twice. And how I would benefit here from a compiler cross check, I don't understand at all.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Which is why one can now do empty "diamonds" in Java 7+

Comment: Yes and that's good for generics, but I still miss the equivalent of C#'s `var` in Java.

Comment: As for it being "un-java-like", this (cheesy) story comes to mind ;) http://9gag.com/gag/2308699/-this-is-how-things-are-done-around-here

Comment: Further, the return type of a function is often either obvious or unnecessary, and even in cases where it is not your IDE can flag up the type in half a second.

Comment: @KonradMorawski Cute story, but it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @GlennNelson to a degree. Doing things the way we used to just because that's the way we used to. It serves as its own justification

Comment: @KonradMorawski No, I'd say that the feel, style, and overall design of the Java language is a result of collaboration amongst many software engineers and computer scientists with much more experience and understanding of things than you or I could ever hope to accomplish. Java isn't an accident, it is a piece of engineering. This isn't a bunch of monkeys running about with mob rule. So no, it doesn't apply. Not to a degree.

Comment: @GlennNelson of course, but so is C# (yes I'm biased, I prefer it over Java). I am not saying Java's design is accidental - that's a bit of a straw man argument on your part now :) Obviously it's a result of certain design choices, and these choices can be debated or questioned, why shouldn't they be. They're not just right or wrong, trade offs are involved. Things like verbosity are a matter of taste, mine may be different than yours and no amount of design experience can remove the subjectivity factor. Btw correct me if I'm wrong, but lambda expressions were once considered un-java-like, too

Comment: I believe the official quote `Humans benefit from the redundancy` is the real answer to the current question, because every justification I've read seems a gratuitous, unfounded and ridiculous excuse from Java designers: Both C# and C++ have the feature, C# and C++ designers are no less competent than Java's, and everyone is happy using it. What is it that would causes Java developers to be different from C# or C++ developers? This is why I agree with @KonradMorawski, "This is how things are done here" seems *again* to be the real behind-the-scenes reason for that.

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive:  http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286 .  This is authored by Brian Goetz, who is the Java Language Architect at Oracle, so there's a strong likelihood this will be implemented.

Comment: @Konrad Morawski: "Doing things the way we used to just because that's the way we used to. It serves as its own justification": I agree with Glen Nelson. It is not about being against innovation. Java was designed this way and should stay this way. Why have the Java of the 90-ties, the Java of the 00-ies, and so on? I hate languages that are like a moving target and can never decide what they want to be. If one wants a JVM with type inference, there is Scala. Scala was designed with type inference from the beginning and I find that a much better, cleaner approach that bolting it on to Java.

Answer (score 16):

Well, first off, type inference has **nothing** to do with the maturity of the runtime, whether that runtime is a 30 year old CPU or a VM that is so new the bits are still shiny.  it's all about the compiler.

That said, it is allowed for generics, the reason why it's not allowed for non-generic types seems to be because of philosophy -- there's nothing preventing the designers from adding it.

Update: looks like java 10 supports it —- http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, when Java was designed at the beginning of the nineties type inference was not that popular among mainstream languages (but it was already a very well known concept, e.g. in ML). So, I can imagine that type inference was probably not supported because Java was aimed at programmers coming from C++, Pascal, or other mainstream languages that did not have it (principle of least surprise).

Also, one of the design principles of Java is to write things explicitly to make sure that the programmer and the compiler have the same understanding of the code: duplicating information reduces the chances of errors. Of course, it may be a matter of taste whether typing a few more characters is worth the extra safety it provides, but this was the design philosophy followed for Java: write things explicitly.

I do not know if Java will get type inference in the future but IMO that would be a big revolution for the language (as Glenn Nelson mentioned, it was described as "un-java-like") and then one might also consider dropping the name Java in favour of a new name.

If you want to use a JVM language with type inference you can use Scala.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few possible reasons. One is that explicit typing is self-documenting. Java generally makes this a priority over concision. Another reason might be in cases where the type is somewhat ambiguous. Like when a type or any subtype might satisfy a routine. Let's say you want to use a List, but someone comes along and uses a method exclusive to ArrayList. The JIT would infer an ArrayList and carry on even if you wanted a compilation error.

Comment: How does GridBagLayout gridbag = new GridBagLayout(); add to self documentation? Its pure repetition.

Comment: It disambiguates from a case where the two types are not the same. You could just as easily assign an instance of a subclass.

Comment: `Let's say you want to use a List, but someone comes along and uses a method exclusive to ArrayList. The JIT would infer an ArrayList and carry on even if you wanted a compilation error` - I don't understand this bit. Type inference takes place at the moment of instatiating a variable, not calling a method on it. Could you perhaps show an example of what you meant?

Comment: @KonradMorawski: I assume he means that if a method returns ArrayList, the type will be inferred to that. If you want to treat a type as something other than the return type, you can't use inference. I don't understand how this could ever be a problem in a codebase anywhere near sane, though.

Comment: the JIT would play no part whatsoever in type inference. type inference is a compile-time phenomenon. and if a variable is declared as a reference to a List, trying to access ArrayList members on it won't type check and you get a compilation error

Answer (score 0):

It contradicts the well-established recommendation to declare variables using the most generic interface that will fit your needs, and initialize them with an appropriate implementing class, like in

```
Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
```

Effectively,

```
var names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

is nothing but syntactic sugar for

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you want that, your IDE can produce it from the `new ArrayList<String>()` expression with "one click" (refactor / create local variable), but remember that it contradicts the "use interfaces" recommendation.

Comment: It only matters in the field outside that class.